# Guideline 2.4.1 - Performance - Hardware Compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, app-store, ios-simulator

when upload app on app store i got below error message from app store and app is reject.I already told my app for iPhone not iPad[image].I selected deployment info-->device-->iPhone (not universal and iPad)please check below message

> Guideline 2.4.1 - Performance - Hardware Compatibility
>   We noticed that your app did not run or display as expected when viewed on iPad running iOS 11.4.1.
>   Please keep in mind that even if your app is designed only for iPhone, users should be able to use your app in iPad.

so what should I do.....

Answer (score 0):

It is not the issue with supported devices, even if the app is for iPhone only, it has to run on iPhone resolution on an iPad. Check your app if it supports iPhone 4 and if not fix the issues with it and re submit.